# Filtering text file based on the timestamp at the start of the row

Tags: python

I have this giant text file and I want to take the lines that have data associated at the top of the minute. Here are a couple of lines that are from this said text file. This is a snippet of over 36 hours of data. What I mean by associated is that the 8 points of data trailing the timestamp.

```
2020-08-03 22:17:12,0,0,4803,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.8917
2020-08-03 22:17:13,0,0,4802,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.8925
2020-08-03 22:17:14,0,0,4805,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.9341
2020-08-03 22:17:15,0,0,4802,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.9683
2020-08-03 22:17:18,0,0,4802,4800,91,28.05,23.05,58.978
...
```

I can't find a way for python to look at the seconds part of the timestamp and then create a new list with only the data associated with ":00" seconds.

```
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    line = line.split(",")
    masterlist.extend(line) #this is putting the information into one list
    altmasterlist.append(line) #this is putting the lines of information into a list

for line in altmasterlist:
    if ":00" in line:
        finalmasterlist.extend(line) #Nothing is entering this if statement

print(finalmasterlist)
```

Am I even in the right area with these two for loops?

Comment: What do you mean by "data associated at the top of the minute"?

Comment: Rather than "if ':00' in line", you should have "line.split(':')[-1]=='00'".

Comment: This has a pandas one liner written all over it

Comment: Your misconception is that ``altmasterlist`` does *not* contain lines, but a lines split into fields. You want to check only the *first field* of each line for a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said your file is huge? Maybe it is best to split the data as you read it.

You can do so without libraries:

```py
zero_entries = []

with open(path_to_file, "r") as file:
    # iterates over every line 
    for line in file:
        # finds the end if the first cell
        timestamp_end = line.index(',')

        # checks if the timestamp ends on zero seconds and adds it to a list.
        if line[:timestamp_end].endswith(':00'):
            zero_entries.append(line)

print(zero_entries)
```

I assume your timestamp will always be the first element of the line.

---

Depending on your file size this will be much faster than Trenton's solution (I tested it with ~58k lines):

```py
import time
import pandas as pd
path = r"txt.csv"

start = time.time()
zero_entries = []

with open(path, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        semi_index = line.index(',')
        if line[:semi_index].endswith(':00'):
            zero_entries.append(line)

end = time.time()
print(end-start)



start = time.time()

df = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, parse_dates=[0])
# using Boolean indexing to select data when seconds = 00
top_of_the_minute = df[df[0].dt.second == 0]

end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

```
0.04886937141418457 # built-in
0.27971720695495605 # pandas
```

Comment: Yep! That is it!! Thank you! I don't know if I was ever going to get that combination correct!

Answer (score 2):

- Using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html)

  - This can be accomplished with a 1 line vectorized operation.
  - As the `timeit` test shows, using pandas is 106 ms slower for 1M rows of data, than reading the file using `with open`, and a `str` method to find `:00`.

    - The main difference is, pandas has converted all of the data to the correct `dtype`, (e.g. `datetime`, `int`, and `float`), and the code is cleaner.
    - Additionally, the data is now in an useful format to perform timeseries analysis on and to plot, though I'd recommend adding column names.

      - `df.columns = ['datetime', ..., 'price']`
- Read the file in with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and parse the dates in column 0.

  - Using `header=None` because no headers are provided in the test data
- Using [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data) to select dates when the seconds are 0

  - Use the [`.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor) accessor to get the `.second`.

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the file which apparently has no header and parse the date column
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, parse_dates=[0])

# using Boolean indexing to select data when seconds = 00
top_of_the_minute = df[df[0].dt.second == 0]

# save the data
top_of_the_minute.to_csv('clean.csv', header=False, index=False)

# display(top_of_the_minute)
                    0  1  2     3     4   5      6      7        8
5 2020-08-03 22:17:00  0  0  4803  4800  91  28.05  24.05  58.8917
6 2020-08-03 22:17:00  0  0  4802  4800  91  28.05  24.05  58.8925
7 2020-08-03 22:17:00  0  0  4805  4800  91  28.05  24.05  58.9341
8 2020-08-03 22:17:00  0  0  4802  4800  91  28.05  24.05  58.9683
9 2020-08-03 22:17:00  0  0  4802  4800  91  28.05  23.05  58.9780

# example: rename columns
top_of_the_minute.columns = ['datetime', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'p1', 'p2', 'p3']

# example: plot the data
p = top_of_the_minute.plot('datetime', 'p3')
p.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
p.set_xlim('2020-08', '2020-09')
```

[image]

### `test.csv`

```py
2020-08-03 22:17:12,0,0,4803,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.8917
2020-08-03 22:17:13,0,0,4802,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.8925
2020-08-03 22:17:14,0,0,4805,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.9341
2020-08-03 22:17:15,0,0,4802,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.9683
2020-08-03 22:17:18,0,0,4802,4800,91,28.05,23.05,58.978
2020-08-03 22:17:00,0,0,4803,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.8917
2020-08-03 22:17:00,0,0,4802,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.8925
2020-08-03 22:17:00,0,0,4805,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.9341
2020-08-03 22:17:00,0,0,4802,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.9683
2020-08-03 22:17:00,0,0,4802,4800,91,28.05,23.05,58.978
```

### `%%timeit` test

#### create test data

```py
# read test.csv
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, parse_dates=[0])

# create a dataframe with 1M rows 
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000)

# save the new test data
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

#### `test_sk`

```py
def test_sk(path: str):
    zero_entries = []

    with open(path, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            semi_index = line.index(',')
            if line[:semi_index].endswith(':00'):
                zero_entries.append(line)
    return zero_entries


%%timeit
result_sk = test_sk('test.csv')
[out]:
668 ms ± 5.69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

#### `test_tm`

```py
def test_tm(path: str):
    df = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, parse_dates=[0])
    return df[df[0].dt.second == 0]


%%timeit
result_tm = test_tm('test.csv')
[out]:
774 ms ± 7.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: and there's the one liner..probably the easiest/most straightforward way

Answer (score 1):

give this a try

```py
finalmasterlist2 = []
for i in range(len(altmasterlist)):
    if ":00" in altmasterlist[i][0]:
        finalmasterlist2.extend(altmasterlist[i])
print("finalemasterlist_2")
print(finalmasterlist2)
```

INPUT:

```
2020-08-03 22:17:12,0,0,4803,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.8917 
2020-08-03 22:17:13,0,0,4802,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.8925  
2020-08-03 22:17:00,0,0,4805,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.9341  
2020-08-03 22:17:15,0,0,4802,4800,91,28.05,24.05,58.9683  
2020-08-03 22:17:18,0,0,4802,4800,91,28.05,23.05,58.978
```

OUTPUT:
`['2020-08-03 22:17:00', '0', '0', '4805', '4800', '91', '28.05', '24.05', '58.9341']`